# using Instagram API in Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, instagram, instagram-api

I’m developing an app for android using Phonegap/Cordova that uses the Instagram API. According to the [Instagram documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en), I need to direct the user to the Instagram authorization URL in which the user will be asked if they would like to grant my application access to his/her Instagram data:

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

Once a user authorizes my application, Instagram issues a redirect to the “redirect_uri” in the above code. The problem is that since the app is running on Android, there’s no url to direct the user to, and without a redirect_uri the code won’t work.

So do you know any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use phonegap's [in app browser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) to redirect them to your website (Or any website. Maybe instagram.com) after the client authorizes your app, capture the token (by parsing the address in the phone gap browser), then close the in-app browser. This would use Client Side Implicit Authentication:

[image]